# Совместимость кода.js с IE7

Tags: совместимость, internet-explorer

Обнаружил, что мой код не совместим с IE7 и после нескольких секунд размышлений решил спросить у опытных разработчиков, стоит ли думать о таких ископаемых браузерах? Вы заботитесь о совместимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@shatal](/users/14189/shatal), процент поддерживаемых фич (устаревшие браузеры, адаптивная верстка, дата-биндинг и прочее) прямо пропорционально бюджету проекта, скажем так. Контакт в свое время предлагал любителям старья пересесть на вещи поновее; забегая вперед, скажу, что браузеры сейчас склонны к самообновлению, и проблема через некоторое время сама вымрет, поэтому я бы поддержку старых браузеров отложил в самый дальний угол. Ну и не забывайте смотреть не общую статистику использования браузеров в мире, а региональную, тот же Китай довольно сильно влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас крупный (банковский) сайт, то скорее всего нужно поддерживать этот браузер, но там это решают менеджеры.

Если это Ваш личный сайт - то можете смело игнорировать (и даже IE8).